# Ubuntu - bulk file rename

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rename

I have a folder containing a sequence of files whose names bear the form `filename-white.png`.  e.g.

```
images
  arrow-down-white.png
  arrow-down-right-white.png
  ...
  bullets-white.png
  ...
  ...
  video-white.png
```

I want to strip out the `-white` bit so the names are simply `filename.png`. I have played around, dry run with `-n`, with the Linux `rename` command. However, my knowledge of regexes is rather limited so I have been unable to find the right way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in the directory above images, the command is

`rename "s/-white.png/.png/" images/*`

If your current directory is `images`, then run `rename "s/-white.png/.png/" ./*` instead. To do a dry run, just attach a `-n` like you said:

`rename -n "s/-white.png/.png/" images/*`

or

`rename -n "s/-white.png/.png/" ./*`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I am afraid that gives `Substitution replacement not terminated at (eval 1)  line 1`

Comment: are you sure you copied it correctly, including the last slash after .png? it worked on my machine

Comment: oops!  I had missed out that terminating slash.  Thank you for your help.